# How to use json file as an input for Testdata driven testing in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have an application where in i need to automate the testing using Selenium C# and I want to use a json file as storage of the Users' name and password. Can you help show how to implement this?

I am using this code

```
public class CredentialReader
{

    public static string GetProjectRootDirectory()
    {
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        return currentDirectory.Split("bin")[0];
    }


    private static JObject GetTestDataJsonObject()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(GetProjectRootDirectory(), "TestData", "login.json");
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path));
        return jObject;
    }

    public static int GetTestDataInt(string label)
    {
        var jObject = GetTestDataJsonObject();
        return Int32.Parse(jObject[label].ToString());
    }

    public static List<string> GetTestDataArray(string label)
    {
        var jObject = GetTestDataJsonObject();
        return jObject[label].ToObject<List<string>>(); ;
    }

}
```

but i am having build error for **Username** as it cannot be converted in string

```
        internal void EnterLoginDetails()
        {
            List<string> Username = CredentialReader.GetTestDataArray("Username");
            txtUserName.SendKeys(Username);
            txtPassword.SendKeys(Password);
            btnLogin.Click();
        }
```

Here is the Json file

```
{

    "Username1": "Test_PM",
    "Password": "Password123"
}

{

    "Username2": "Test_Viewing",
    "Password": "Password123"
}
```

Comment: a json string of your file is not valid

Comment: can you specify?

Comment: This will be your homework. After this you will not need to ask the question

Comment: json file shown is not valid. Code tries to fetch an array from the json file where as the file just has 2 json objects and not an array.